# How to upgrade android version in spice Mi 350n

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates, 4.1-jelly-bean, 4.2-jelly-bean, spice-mi-350

I have a android phone spice Mi 350n, android version is 2.3.4. I want to upgrade it, is it possible, if yes upto which version?

Any link for tutorial is helpful.

Thanks!

Edit - Come on guys, if you are a android user you must know that updating android is not a general question can be asked for all android smartphone. Update depends on particular device/hardware etc.

Comment: Please see: [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14766/16575) / [When will my device get the Android 4.1 update (Jelly Bean)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/24575/16575) / [When will my device get the Android 4.2 update?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32589/16575) / [How do I upgrade to a new version of Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4184/16575) / [What is involved in upgrading Android to a later version, if the manufacturer no longer supports the device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28784/16575)

Comment: One more global source: [How do I update the OS on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/16575)